# Assigning command output to variable gives strange results

Tags: shell-script

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJECT_DIR=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)

COMMANDS_CODE=$(php $PROJECT_DIR/bin/console generate:code)

echo $COMMANDS_CODE
```

The output has all newlines stripped (which doesn't happen if I call the script directly) and contains some strange paths at the beginning like this:

```
/bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home 
/initrd.img /lib /lib64 /lost+found 
/media /mnt /opt /proc /root /sbin 
/selinux /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var /vmlinuz 
... here starts the actual output but without any newlines ...
```

(The above is actualy one long string which is echoed I just added some newlines for readability)

What's happening there?

If I do a

```
php bin/console generate:code
```

in my project dir in my bash shell everything works fine.

Comment: Try echo "$COMMANDS_CODE"

Comment: @Tim thanks! that worked…… uh… I really know nothing about shell as I just learned again. How come? Care to post an answer so you can have your well deserved reputation? :-)

Comment: No prob Max, answer added. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping the variable in double quotation marks.
Example: `echo "$COMMANDS_CODE"`

You can learn more about shell variables and quotation marks [here](http://linuxsig.org/files/bash_scripting.html), under the section "The Importance of Quotation Marks".