# How can I automatically target the output of a download script

Tags: shell-script, variable

I've written a pretty basic script that let's me download a file using a URL. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# A script that downloads a file based on url

function filedl() {
  echo "What is the url for the file?"
  read FILEURL
  wget $FILEURL
  echo "Download complete"
}

filedl
```

What I'd like to be able to do is target the downloaded file immediately after it's downloaded and automatically move it to a pre-defined directory using a further command or function in my script.

I have read a few threads about how to pipe an output to a variable but I can't work out how to do that with my script. These are the threads I've read:

- [shell script - How can I pipe the output of a program or function into a variable? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/how-can-i-pipe-the-output-of-a-program-or-function-into-a-variable)
- [shell script - Assigning command output to variable gives strange results - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44202/assigning-command-output-to-variable-gives-strange-results?rq=1)
- [bash - How do I redirect output to a variable in shell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559076/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-variable-in-shell)

I've tried to create a new variable with something like the following but it didn't seem to work:

`NEWFILE=$(wget $FILEURL)`

I also tried a variation of my script with this modification of the function call:

`NEWFILE=$(filedl)` <-- This also didn't seem to do anything.

Finally, I moved my commands out of a function and just listed each command with variations of the variable definition attempts I described above. I still couldn't figure out how to do this.

I'm still pretty new to shell scripting so apologies if I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than capturing the file in a variable, unnecessarily putting the whole thing in memory, use `wget`'s `--output-document`/`-O` flag and one of these two variations:

```
wget -O /path/to/file ... http://example.com/foobar
wget -O - ... http://example.com/foobar > /path/to/file
```

...where `/path/to/file` is any path+filename you desire. (And `...` just represents any other flags or params you may be using.)

Or if you want to preserve the default name of the downloaded file use `--directory-prefix` or `-P` and just specify the directory to which the file should be saved.

```
wget -P /some/path ... http://example.com/foobar
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but, in this case, I'm happy to use the downloaded file's name. I just want to move it to another directory. The `-O` option, as I understand it, requires me to give it a new file name?

Comment: Ok, I modified the line to this:

`wget --directory-prefix $FILEURL > ~/Downloads`

I got an error:

`./file-dl.sh: line 8: /Users/pauljacobson/Downloads: Is a directory`

The download failed with both the `-P` and `--directory-prefix` options.

Comment: `wget --directory-prefix ~/Downloads $FILEURL`